# React state's previous value equals new value with setInterval

Tags: reactjs

I am setting up a setInterval with some VideoPlayer iFrame. Every 10 seconds or so, I need to call an API to update back-end with new state of the video played.

I want to have another check on client, if the data from previous state is same as new one (This case occurs when the video is paused for longer duration) I don't want to call the back-end API.

```
    const [coveredArray, setCoveredArray] = useState([]);
    const intervalPeriod = 5000;
    const interval = useRef();
```

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window !== "undefined" && isOpen && player) {

            console.log('SUB');
            // Setup an interval to update watch time
            interval.current = window.setInterval(async () => {
                const totalCoveredArray = await player?.api.getTotalCoveredArray();

                setCoveredArray((prevCoveredArray) => {
                    console.log('1', prevCoveredArray);
                    console.log('2', totalCoveredArray);

                    if (!isEqual(prevCoveredArray, totalCoveredArray)) {
                        console.log('New');
                        return totalCoveredArray;
                    } else {
                        console.log('Same');
                        return prevCoveredArray;
                    }
                });

            }, intervalPeriod);

            return () => {
                // Clear interval on exit
                console.log('UN-SUB')
                setCoveredArray([]);
                return window.clearInterval(interval.current)
            };
        }
    }, [isOpen, player]);
```

The problem with this code is, `prevCoveredArray` and `totalCoveredArray` are same everytime the interval is run. How is previousState similar to newState (which is not set yet)?

This is logged in console:

[image: Console Log]

Any help/pointer would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: maybe if you lost the reference destructuring the array [...prevCoveredArray] and [...totalCoveredArray]

Comment: Ah, totally missed that. Thanks! It works now

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `typeof window !== "undefined"` in the `useEffect`, since `useEffect` only runs on the client